# clang tool outputs "cannot chdir into ."

Tags: c++, clang

I'm making a Clang refactoring tool using Replacements. While trying to run the tool, LLVM throws this error:

```
LLVM ERROR: Cannot chdir into "."!
```

I tried to run gdb on the tool and it looks like the problem is when I try to run the tool:

```
if (int Result = Tool.run(newFrontendActionFactory(&Finder).get()))
```

My system is Ubuntu 20.04 and googling it, it looks like this error was discussed in Qt forum but the problem is applicable to clang tools too. Any suggestions as to how to solve this?